# Show that at most half of the positive divisors of a positive integer end in 3.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we assume that there does exist such an integer $n$, then it has to be 9 mod 10. Is this useful at all? I have no idea where to go from that.

By the way, I saw this problem in some old math test (I think from MOSP). But I cannot find the solution. I would appreciate any hints/ideas on this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has a prime factor $2$ at least half the factors will be even and can't end in $3$.  Similarly if it has a prime factor $5$, so all the prime factors will end in $1,3,7,9$.  You can think of each factor as pulling from a multiset of $1's, 3's, 7's$ and $9's$.  If there is one $7$ you can match up each factor without a $7$ with one that has it.  At most one ends in $3$.  Similarly if there are more $7$s at most half the factors end in $3$ so there can't be any factors ending in $7$.  The same argument applies to factors ending in $9$.  The ones ending in $1$ don't matter.  If we have at least one $3$ again not more than half the factors end in $3$ and we are done.